# Batch file to create a folder based on current date & time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

we have a simple batch file that creates a backup of a folder and appends the date & time to the end.

We use this incrementally and it outputs a folder such as "data 28-04-13".

I would like to add the time to the end of this, however my code outputs time as HH:MM, which is not valid for a folder name as it includes a colon (:).

Please could someone modify my code to remove the :, or replace it with a ".".

Thank You

```
@echo off & for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%A in ('date/t') do (
set DateDay=%%A
set DateMonth=%%B
set DateYear=%%C
)

@echo off & for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%D in ('time/t') do (
set DateTime=%%D
)

set CurrentDate=%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-%DateTime%

md "F:\MobilePC\data %CurrentDate"
```

Answered my own question

So, this was the easiest way for me:

```
set CurrentDate=%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
```

Which outputs "31-10-13-11.35"

Comment: Use the default batch variables of %date% %time% to do it?

Comment: as you can see %time% outputs the time in the following HH:MM, which is not valid for a folder name as it includes a colon.

Comment: The `time` variable also includes spaces in the AM which have to be accounted for.  My suggestion below using `WMIC` eliminates the issues for XP Pro and higher.

Comment: question and answer itself worked for me...thank

Comment: set folder=%date%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%-%time:~9,2%
set folder=%folder: =% rem to remove white spaces incase of single digit time or month

Answer (score 25):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

The built in cmd date and time variables are user configurable and so are unreliable for any general batch file.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Answer (score 8):

You can set current date and time by doing this.
I am using this daily in my batch file.

```
%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
```

ouput :

```
201509141639 ( 14th sept 2015 04:39 PM )
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone :  
in this ex. it will separate date by YYYYMMDDHHMM format. 
<br/>
I am using this to generate my copied file list as below.
<br/>
xcopy /e /y C:\Upload C:\Archive >> C:\Result\%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt 

it create text file with copied file name.

Answer (score 7):

```
rem replace : with .
set myTime=%time::=.%

rem remove cents of second
set myTime=%myTime:~0,-3%
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will create a folder named with current date & time and copies the full content from "D:\Tally Data" to "08-10-2016 17 23" folder.

It requires a folder named "Tally Data" in your computer's D drive.(copy below code to a text document and save as a DOS batch file)

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a

set time=%TIME:~0,2%" "%TIME:~3,2%

mkdir C:\%date:/=%" "%time%\Backup

xcopy "D:\Tally Data" C:\%date:/=%" "%time%\Backup /E /S /Q /Y
```

Comment: Please avoid writing your answers in full-caps.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Run a search for "Replace a substring."

Comment: Thanks, so I am trying to work this out, I have done the following

set CurrentDateUnedited=%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-%DateTime%
set CurrentDate=%CurrentDateUnedited%
echo.%CurrentDate%
set str=%str::=%
echo.%CurrentDate%

But because it is a colon I am not sure how to parse that in to the code?

Comment: I think you need to `echo %str%` at the end instead of `echo %CurrentDate%`.  Also, as @SamN said, you can use the built in `%time%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setlocal
   set "time=%time::=%"
   rem check that date has / delimeter if not replace it for valid
   md %date:/=%_%time:~0,-3%
 endlocal
```